# Where did the $\pi n$ come from?

Tags: trigonometry, quantum-mechanics

So I'm reading Landau&Lifshitz's book on quantum mechanics and there's this solution to the problem of energy levels in a non-symmetrical potential well. All is good but I don't quite get where the $\pi n$ comes from after eliminating $\delta$. Isn't the function $\arcsin[\sin(x)]$ supposed to change in sign after $x=\pi$?
For a bit more context here are the two lines that made me puzzled:
$\sin(\delta)=\frac{k\hbar}{\sqrt{2mU_1}},\sin(ka+\delta)=\!-\!\frac{k\hbar}{\sqrt{2mU_2}}\!\implies\! ka=\pi n-\arcsin\left(\frac{k\hbar}{\sqrt{2mU_1}}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{k\hbar}{\sqrt{2mU_2}}\right)$

To be fair, he mentions that n=1,2,3... and that the values of $\arcsin$ are taken between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I still don't quite get how that explains everything.

Comment: The principal branch of arcsine, which I will denote with a capital, relates to the $n$th branch as follows: $$\arcsin_n(x)=\pi\cdot n+(-1)^n\operatorname{Arcsin}(x)$$If that helps

Comment: It does, thank you!